# Add a series of dates with a series of hours

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe 'df' with two columns: 'Date' and 'Time Start (UTM)' (see attached png).

I WISH a new column with the addition of both, for example:

```
Date                 Time Start (UTM)  New Column
2018-04-10 00:00:00  13:03:00          2018-04-10 13:03:00
2018-04-10 00:00:00  14:01:00          2018-04-10 14:01:00
```

dtypes are:

```
df['Date'] --> dtype = datetime64[ns]

df['Time Start (UTM)'] --> dtype = object
```

But when I see element by element I get

```
df['Time Start (UTM)'].ix[0]

datetime.time(13, 36)

df['Date'].ix[0]

Timestamp('2018-04-04 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.to_timedelta()` function for this one

```
df['DateTime'] = df.Date + pd.to_timedelta(df.Time)
df
```

Output:

```
    Date        Time        DateTime
0   2018-04-10  13:03:00    2018-04-10 13:03:00
1   2018-04-10  14:01:00    2018-04-10 14:01:00
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to convert your `Date` column to `str`, concatenate with `Time`, then pass to `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['Time'])

print(df)

        Date      Time            DateTime
0 2018-04-10  13:03:00 2018-04-10 13:03:00
1 2018-04-10  14:01:00 2018-04-10 14:01:00
```